# Nucleophilicity methanol vs water

Tags: nucleophilicity

I have a short question: Which among Methanol and water will be a better nucleophile for a reaction carried out in some polar protic solvent .
Searching over the internet suggests that methoxide ion may be more nucleophilic than hydroxide ion, is that true? If it is, does that automatically imply methanol being more nucleophilic than water?
Also, on what precise factors does it depend?